# Updating FK value in Many to One relationships

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to update a record in Table 1 that includes a foreign key to Table 2. The current record in Table 1 points to id=2 on Table 2. I would like it to point to Id=4 on table 2.

I am using Http PUT to update the value. The body of http PUT call is

```
URL: http://localhost:8080/table1s/1

{
  "name": "Dependent 16",
  "tabId":"http://localhost:8080/table2s/4"
}
```

I know that this value gets correctly interpreted as the Table 2 record. However, while processing the PUT request, the updated record is dropped and the old value of the foreign key is retained.

From digging around in Java libraries, it appears that my configuration of association between Table 1 and Table 2 is the likely cause.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

'''Table creation SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(32) not null)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(32) not null,
  tab_id int not null,
  CONSTRAINT FK_table1_table2
    FOREIGN KEY (tab_id)
    REFERENCES table2 (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

insert into table2 (id, name) 
    values(1, "First row");

insert into table2 (id, name) 
    values(2, "Second row");

insert into table2 (id, name) 
    values(3, "Third row");

insert into table2 (id, name) 
    values(4, "Fourth row");

insert into table2 (id, name) 
    values(5, "Fifth row");


insert into table1 (id, name, tab_id) 
    values(1, "Dependent 1", 2);

insert into table1 (id, name, tab_id) 
    values(2, "Dependent 2", 2);

insert into table1 (id, name, tab_id) 
    values(3, "Dependent 3", 5);
```

''' End SQL

'''Java entities - Table 1

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
@XmlRootElement
public class Table1 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 32)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tabId")
    private Table2 tabId;
}
```

--------------------Java Entities - Table 2

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "table2")
@XmlRootElement
public class Table2 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 32)
    private String name;

}
```

--------------------Table 1 Repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface table1Repository extends JpaRepository<Table1, Long>{

}
```

--------------------Table 2 Repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource()
public interface table2Repository extends JpaRepository<Table2, Long>{

}
```

I expect that after the PUT request, the query result should change from

```
select * from table1;
+----+--------------+--------+
| id | name         | tab_id |
+----+--------------+--------+
|  1 | Dependent 1 |      2 |
|  2 | Dependent 2  |      2 |
|  3 | Dependent 3  |      5 |
+----+--------------+--------+
```

to

```
select * from table1;

+----+--------------+--------+
| id | name         | tab_id |
+----+--------------+--------+
|  1 | Dependent 14 |      4 |
|  2 | Dependent 2  |      2 |
|  3 | Dependent 3  |      5 |
+----+--------------+--------+
```

Comment: Where is the code of the controller taking the JSON as input, transforming it into a Table1 instance, and saving it?

Comment: I am using JPA repositories. The repositories handle JSON to entity mapping and exposing the web interface.

Comment: Your JSON has a field named `table2Id`. Your entity has a field named `tabId`. How could they magically match?

Comment: Nizet, thank you for pointing this out. I had copied the incorrect JSON into the post.

Comment: Found a workaround to this problem. If I override the repository's PUT behaviour using a controller, then I can simply call save on the repository and the FK gets updated. Still not sure why the behaviour exposed by repository did not work.